# Why modifying two-dimensional array with function doesn't work?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, copy

It is my code for working with two dimensional arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_array(double ** m, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%.2f ", m[i][j]);

        printf("\n");
    }
    return;
}

double ** allocate_array(int n)
{
    double ** m = (double **)calloc(sizeof(double *), n);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        m[i] = (double *)calloc(sizeof(double), n);

    return m;
}

void free_array(double ** m, int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        free(m[i]);
    free(m);

    return;
}

// array_sum(result, sum1, sum2, dimensions)
void array_sum(double ** sum, double ** x1, double ** x2, int n)
{
    double **s;
    s = allocate_array(n);

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            s[i][j] = x1[i][j] + x2[i][j];

    memcpy(sum, s, sizeof(**s)*n);
    free_array(s, n);

    printf("hhh\n");
    print_array(sum, n);
    return;
```

}

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    FILE* f;
    f = fopen("array.txt", "r");
    fscanf(f, "%d", &n);

    double **m;
    m = allocate_array(n);

    int i; int j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            fscanf(f, "%lf", &m[i][j]);

    //print_array(m, n);
    double **k;
    k = allocate_array(n);
    array_sum(k, m, m, n);
    //print_array(k, n);




    free_array(m, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Why freeing of s results that sum also freed and as result function doesn't return correct result? What I am should use for modifying objects like arrays os structs in function through pointer?

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion the problem is actually in `memcpy(sum, s, sizeof(**s)*n);`, which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: You're copying the pointers of `s` to `sum` and then `free`ing `s`s pointers. That leaves the pointers of `sum` dangling.

Comment: From what i see, `s` isn't even needed for what you should be doing in `array_sum`. You're (a) leaking all the pointers allocated back in `main` held in the sequence referenced by `sum`, (b) blasting over them with the pointers you locally allocated for `s`, (c) using the wrong size calculation for your memory copy, and finally (d) freeing all the pointers now held jointly in `s` and `sum`, thereby sending a big stack of dangling pointers in `sum` back to `main()`.

Comment: I need to use something like this?

    void copy_array(double ** to, double ** src, int n)
    {
     int i;
     for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      memcpy(to[i], src[i], sizeof(double)*n);

     return;
    }

Comment: Get `memcpy` out of your head. I'd do [something like this](http://pastebin.com/nTsDjUZf).

Answer (score 2):

For starters this statement

```
memcpy(sum, s, sizeof(**s)*n);
               ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is invalid.

It should look like

```
memcpy(sum, s, sizeof( *s ) * n);
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This statement copies pointers from array pointed to by s to the array pointed to by sum.

However after this statement

```
free_array(s, n);
```

these pointers become invalid because the memory pointed to by these pointers was freed.

Take into account that you allocated n + 1 arrays that occupy different extents of memory and you can not use `memcpy` to copy all these arrays.

Just write

```
void array_sum(double ** sum, double ** x1, double ** x2, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            sum[i][j] = x1[i][j] + x2[i][j];

    printf("hhh\n");
    print_array(sum, n);
}
```

Also you should add statement

```
free_array(k, n);
```

in the main to free allocated arrays pointed to by k..